# Find a pattern (of a child tag) and replace the entire parent tag at XML files, without using sed tool

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl, xml

Is there a way to find a pattern (of a child tag)
and replace the entire parent tag, using regular expressions? 
I'm working from a Linux server without a graphics environment.

I have XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<bookstore>  
  <book category="COOKING">  
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>  
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>  
    <year>2005</year>  
    <price>30.00</price>  
  </book>  
  <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>  
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>  
    <year>2005</year>  
    <price>29.99</price>  
  </book>  
  <book category="WEB">  
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>  
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>  
    <year>2003</year>  
    <price>39.95</price>  
  </book>  
</bookstore>
```

I need a shell script that finds the pattern:

```
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
```

then replace its complete block:

```
  <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>  
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>  
    <year>2005</year>  
    <price>29.99</price>  
  </book>
```

with:

```
  <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="en">Hamlet</title>  
    <author>William Shakespeare</author>  
  </book>
```

to finally get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<bookstore>  
  <book category="COOKING">  
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>  
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>  
    <year>2005</year>  
    <price>30.00</price>  
  </book>  
  <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="en">Hamlet</title>  
    <author>William Shakespeare</author>  
  </book>  
  <book category="WEB">  
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>  
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>  
    <year>2003</year>  
    <price>39.95</price>  
  </book>  
</bookstore>
```

with something like `<book*<author>J K. Rowling</author>*</book>`,
where `*` is a wildcard for all text or code between `<book` and `<author>...`

I have an idea, using Perl, contemplating these logic steps:

1. Search the line number where the pattern is
2. Identify the line number of parent block open and close  tags
3. Remove all this content, inside these lines.
4. Add the new block inside these lines

But, it is possible, I prefer the first approach.

Comment: Why do you want to do this using a regular expression?  Why not use the proper tool for the job?

Comment: @oswaldog, re: your "reopen" edit just now, neither of the answers in the linked duplicate use sed; why don't they address your concern?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: What are you looking at?  ***Three*** of the answers to [the duplicate target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282488/80216 "Replacement of XML based on attribute content using sed") use `sed`, including the *[accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282488/80216#282519),* which was written by you.

Comment: None of the answers to [the duplicate target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282488/80216 "Replacement of XML based on attribute content using sed"), including the `awk`, Perl and XMLStarlet ones, shows *how* to do what this question asks for: ***replace** an entire block.*

Comment: Whew, I must have misread the GUI somehow, @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'. I saw answers that did not use sed and somehow missed the others, including my own! Anyway, an accepted answer is just an indication that it worked for the asker; the other two (higher-voted!) answers do not use sed. My comment was mainly in reaction to this author proposing a reopening based on "not using sed", but to your point, if there's other issues that separate the questions, then this should be reopened.

Comment: @oswaldog: (1) Your sample data raise a problem: What if the input contains a work whose author is `J.K. Rowling` (as presented on [***her*** web site](https://www.jkrowling.com/)), `J. K. Rowling` (preferred by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._K._Rowling)), `JK Rowling`, ```J K Rowling```, or any other variant?  If you want to handle pattern-matching (and, perhaps, correction / normalization / standardization) in the author field, you should say so explicitly. Otherwise, you might want to use a less problematic example, like `John Grisham`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) You say “I prefer the first approach.”  What “first approach”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with structured document formats, use tools explicitly made for working with these.  Regular expressions are mainly for matching text, and an XML document is not really text but rather data structured in a particular way (and newlines etc. are not always significant).  Likewise, `sed` is a tool for working with lines of text, and this is also not what XML is in general.

Using `xq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

```bsh
xq -x '.book as $new | input |
    (
        .bookstore.book[] |
        select(.author == "J K. Rowling")
    ) |= $new' insert.xml file.xml
```

This uses `xq` to convert both your `bookstore` XML and the element that you want to insert (in `insert.xml`) into JSON.  It then applies a particular `jq` expression to the generated JSON document to extract each entry of the `.bookstore.book` array.  Each element in that array that has an `.author` field equal to exactly `J K. Rowling` is then replaced with the element read from `insert.xml`.

In more detail: We read the contents of the new `.book` object into an internal variable called `$new` and then proceed to get the main document by calling `input`.  The `select()` statement acts on each individual element of the `.bookstore.book` array and pulls out the ones with a particular author.  The result of this is a number of "paths" to these matching `book` entries.  These are updated using `|=` (the update operator) to the `$new` value created earlier.

If you want to provide the new XML on the command line instead of via a file, then use a here-document:

```bsh
xq -x '.book as $new | input |
    (
        .bookstore.book[] |
        select(.author == "J K. Rowling")
    ) |= $new' - file.xml <<'NEW_XML'
<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Hamlet</title>
  <author>William Shakespeare</author>
</book>
NEW_XML
```

Note that the input filename `insert.xml` was replaced by a dash on the command line.

The result, given the data in your question, would be

```xml
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Hamlet</title>
    <author>William Shakespeare</author>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

The `xq` utility can do in-place editing, if you use its `--in-place` (or `-i`) option.

---

For reference, `xq` is translating your XML to the following internal JSON representation, which is then handled by `jq`:

```json
{
  "bookstore": {
    "book": [
      {"@category":"COOKING","title":{"@lang":"en","#text":"Everyday Italian"},"author":"Giada De Laurentiis","year":"2005","price":"30.00"},
      {"@category":"CHILDREN","title":{"@lang":"en","#text":"Harry Potter"},"author":"J K. Rowling","year":"2005","price":"29.99"},
      {"@category":"WEB","title":{"@lang":"en","#text":"Learning XML"},"author":"Erik T. Ray","year":"2003","price":"39.95"}
    ]
  }
}
```

The data to insert would be converted to something equivalent of

```json
{
  "book": {
    "@category": "CHILDREN",
    "title": {
      "@lang": "en",
      "#text": "Hamlet"
    },
    "author": "William Shakespeare"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much!!! I didn't know these tools, amazing, but I noticed the tag <book> is repeated in the final output, at the entry changed. <book><book category="CHILDREN">

Comment: @oswaldog You're right, the tag is repeated, because I was not reading the output closely enough this morning. Give me a moment and I'll clear it up.

Comment: @oswaldog Now fixed. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: You are a guru! @they, really very grateful. Lastly: do you think I can lose data when converting from XML to JSON and vice versa?

Comment: @oswaldog There are definitely JSON documents that can't be represented as XML, but when converting back and forth like this there is no issue. As for performing the actual replacement of data, you could definitely replace more than you bargained for, but that would be just carelessness (not realizing that there are several books by the same author and then replacing _all_ by one single book, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

My preferred approach tends to be to use `xmlstarlet` to manipulate XML data. We declare an `xmlstarlet` variable `$book` to reference the subtree that we need to edit

```
xmlstarlet <682660.xml ed                                               \
    --var book '//book[author="J K. Rowling"]'                          \
    --update '$book' --value ''                                         \
    --update '$book/@category' --value 'CHILDREN'                       \
    --subnode '$book' --type 'elem' --name 'title'  --value 'Hamlet'    \
    --subnode '$book/title' --type attr --name 'lang' --value 'en'      \
    --subnode '$book' --type 'elem' --name 'author' --value 'William Shakespeare'
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Hamlet</title>
    <author>William Shakespeare</author>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

You could also just delete the relevant `<book/>` subtree and append a new one, but that might break sequential processing so I didn't do that here.

Comment: Hi @roaima, I didn't know anything about "xmlstarlet". Is it possible to pass a file as parameters instead  --update and --subnode option?

Comment: @oswaldog I don't know of a way to have `xmlstarlet` read secondary data from a file. It wasn't in your question so I didn't consider it